# What should I do if I accidentally put sensitive data onto Github?

Tags: git, github

Our team accidentally pushed some personal information onto Github in the form of a H2 database file. Is there any way to remove a file cleanly and completely from the server?

Simply doing `git rm xxx.db` does not seem to be the answer because one can easily `git reset --hard` to the head which contains the user data.

On the other hand,

```
git reset --hard [the head before the db file was committed]
```

is also not our preference because there have been more than 10 commits since the database was committed.

What should we do to remove that database file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the GitHub help on [removing sensitive data](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data).

- Run the following to delete the reference to the file in the entire repository – this won't delete the actual file itself:

  ```
  git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
    'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch <somefile>' \
    --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
  ```

  (Make sure to replace `<somefile>` with the path to the file you want removed.)
- Add the file to your `.gitignore`, then `git add` and `git commit` the `.gitignore` file.
- Run `git push origin master --force` to get the changes upstream.

There are some more steps, including [cleaning up the repository](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data#cleanup-and-reclaiming-space) and [writing to GitHub itself](https://github.com/contact) in order to have cached data removed.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you do either of:

- delete the repository
- contact GitHub

dangling commits are still visible. So if it's not just credentials that you can change, do some of the above.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367977/how-to-remove-a-dangling-commit-from-github